# How can I fix the code to make sure it does fetch only if the email is different than the previous one & save fetched data into let "emailInput"?

Tags: javascript, php

This is my JS language which checks if email address typed by user has the structure of the regular email address and also if it isn't the same email address as previous ones (in case user typed them in before), and sends fetch into PHP for checking if the email is inside DB:

```
let emailInput = {};

function checkEmail(event) {
    const body = {email: event.target.value};

    if (emailInput !== body.email && body.email.match(/@.+\..+$/)) {
        emailInput = body.email;
        fetch("http://localhost/BlueFriended_latest/availabilityCheck.php", {
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
            method: "POST"
        })
        .then((response) => {
            response.json();
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

and here is my PHP language for recieving fetch and checking if the email address exists inside DB, and sending back (true or false) depending on the state:

```
<?php
require_once('./classes/DB.php'); // including connection with database 'BlueFriended'

/* $emailData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true)["email"]; */

$emailData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

if (isset($emailData['email'])) {
    $emailData = $emailData['email'];

    if (preg_match("/@.+\..+$/", $emailData)) {
        $statement = DB::prepare("SELECT * FROM users where email = ?");
        $statement->bindParam(1, $emailData);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            $emailAvailable = false;
        } else {
            $emailAvailable = true;
        }
    
        echo json_encode($emailAvailable);
    }
}

exit;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks in advance to those who have time to look at this and help. I am not really good at programming and I could really use a help hand here.

Comment: _"if it isn't the same email address as previous ones"_ What does this mean? Typed them in before when? Your problem is not clearly described.

Comment: oh sorry yeah, well I have email input field where user can type in his email address and code will check if the email is free to use or not (meaning its inside database) and I need to make sure code only checks the same email address only once so it does not add to the traffic if you understand me, thats why I need to save fetched data into that emailInput array for future check, if the email address was already checked and user types that same email address again it won't fetch again but instead look into that array

Comment: And user types that same email address again... when? During that session? That day? Ever? Describe your workflow. Why would the user be typing more than one email address?

Comment: In case if he writes it again, because he is creating an account and if by any chance he puts email that is already inside database and does not know about it, this is what i mean

Comment: just think of when you are creating an account and you type by mistake an email that might already be inside database, and you get some message, and this is what i am trying to achieve

Comment: You have to check every time.

Comment: yes of course :) I am doing it, but I don't want to check fetch for the same email address again if it already has saved data inside that array from which i can find out if it was checked before and is free to use or not, i really don't want to make this hard, hopefully you understand me

Comment: A normal flow is this: The user fills out the form. The user submits the form. You validate the data in the back end (which includes "email already exists" validation). If the validation fails, the server returns an error with the validation errors and they are presented to the user. When they submit the form again, you will need to do the same validations again. When the validation passes, you save the user in the database.

Comment: There's no reason to keep any other states for this in the front end since you still need to validate all the data every time the user submits the form (you can never ever trust data that comes from the client/front end). The performance impact should be negligible for this and it's a common flow. I would categorize this as a premature optimization (starting to optimize your code before you know if it's an issue or not)

Comment: Also, a better way to validate if a string is a valid email email in PHP (instead of using regex), would be to use `filter_var($theEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`. Making a regex that correctly handles all the thousands edge cases is not an easy job and is very error prone (blocking valid emails while allowing invalid etc)

Comment: I know but I do have back end and everything, but I this thing so much. I only need to check if the email that is typed inside the email input field is not inside array emailInput and if not then the fetch will happen. But in case it is inside emailInput array, meaning there already was fetch made for this email then it will just look into that array and look for true or false.

Comment: So could you please help?